# Is the Python Imaging Library not available on PyPI, or am I missing something?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

`easy_install pil` results in an error:

```
Searching for pil
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pil/
Reading http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil
Reading http://effbot.org/zone/pil-changes-115.htm
Reading http://effbot.org/downloads/#Imaging
No local packages or download links found for pil
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse(‘pil’)
```

Any ideas?

--

**UPDATE:**
Hm, asking it to find-links on the Python Ware site seems to be working:

`easy_install -f http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ Imaging`

Got a heap of warnings along the way though. I’ll see how it turns out.

--

**UPDATE:** I can import it in Python using `import Image`, but when I tell Django to syncdb I still get the following error:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
core.userprofile: “avatar”: To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
```

I'm using an ImageField in one of my models.

Answer (score 5):

Of course PIL is on PyPi! Specifically, it's [right here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/1.1.6).

Answer (score 1):

easy_install is case-sensitive.  The package is under PIL.

Answer (score 1):

workaround is in easy_install PIL egg directory create link to this directory in name "PIL"

Answer (score 0):

> import Image

Django tries to import PIL directly:

```
from PIL import Image
```

You should check presence of PIL directory in your site-packages

Answer (score 0):

from http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6054

It seems that there is something wrong with easy_install which installs PIL in the root namespace, installing from sources fixes this, strange.